# Microsoft Word - how to add the split

Tags: microsoft-word

How to add this kind of split in a cell in Word? I need to put values in the cell for column name and row name, like if I use Monday, Tuesday... in the row I need to put the week name in that split part.
[image: Image to show how I want the split to be]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any proper way to do so (i.e. spliting the cell so Word consider it as two separate cells)

Here is a workaround:

1. setting text:

   - type the first (upper right) part of the text
   - press Enter and type second (lower left) text
   - indent  first paragraph to the right
2. border

   - select your cell
   - in home tab - borders - open "borders and shading"
   - select the diagonal border you need

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me. Thank you.